# Does JQuery Support Self Closing Div Tags

Tags: jquery

I was surprised to find out that jQuery does not seem to support self closing div tags. Here is a simple example:

```
    <div id="div1" />
    <div id="div2" />

<script>
$("#div1").html("hello");
$("#div2").html("world");
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UTq4c/1/

When this runs div2 gets removed from the DOM.

I have read that self closing divs are not supported in HTML 5, but I was still surprised by this behavior.

Is there a reason why jquery behaves this way?

Comment: ... Probably because HTML5 doesn't support self-closing `div`s :)

Comment: HTML5 is fresh standard now. Don't allow. http://beyondhtml5andcss3.com/2011/04/04/revenge-of-the-self-closing-tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not jQuery that parses the HTML. It's the browser. The browser, unless served with the `XHTML` mime-type does not recognise the self-closing markup (rightfully so). It interprets the HTML as

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <script>
      ...
    </script>
...
```

The first line of the script (correctly) replaces that with

```
<div id="div1">
  hello
</div>
```

The second line of the script fails to find any `#div2`, so it does not do anything.

Answer (score 2):

HTML 5 does not support self-closing divs therefore your HTML code is interpreted like this:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then,

```
$("#div1").html("hello");
```

replaces `div id="div2"` with "hello" and you see what you see.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with jQuery.

The browser strips out self closing div tags before rendering it if the document type is HTML5. jQuery gets to see only the version of DOM with these elements stripped out by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with jQuery. If you look at how the browser interprets the invalid HTML you provide (in Chrome at least):

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hence when you set the `html()` of `#div1`, you're clearing `#div2` as it's rendered as a child of `#div1`.

This behaviour is the same if [you use native JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/UTq4c/2/):

```
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "hello";
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "world";
```

Comment: @JanDvorak: I feel guilty getting rep points from trivial answers.